# Is there a way to (conditionally) forward fill values in a Pandas DF in a vectorized way based on multiple criteria?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

In the below dataframe, I'm trying to forward fill the `Pos` and `Stop` columns based on the following criteria:

1. If (Prior `Pos` == -1) & (Current `High` < Prior `Stop`)
2. If (Prior `Pos` == 1 ) & (Current  `Low` > Prior `Stop`)

Once either of these conditions is violated, then the values should remain unchanged until the next non-zero instance of `Pos` and `Stop` at which point the above criteria should again be evaluated.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

Open = {'Open':np.array([126.81999969, 126.55999756, 123.16000366, 125.23000336,127.81999969, 126.01000214, 127.81999969, 126.95999908,126.44000244, 125.56999969, 125.08000183, 124.27999878,124.68000031, 124.06999969, 126.16999817, 126.59999847,127.20999908])}
High = {'High': np.array([126.93000031, 126.98999786, 124.91999817, 127.72000122,128.        , 127.94000244, 128.32000732, 127.38999939, 127.63999939, 125.80000305, 125.34999847, 125.23999786, 124.84999847, 126.16000366, 126.31999969, 128.46000671, 127.75      ])}
Low = {'Low' : np.array([125.16999817, 124.77999878, 122.86000061, 125.09999847,125.20999908, 125.94000244, 126.31999969, 126.41999817, 125.08000183, 124.55000305, 123.94000244, 124.05000305, 123.12999725, 123.84999847, 124.83000183, 126.20999908, 126.51999664])}
Close = {'Close': np.array([126.26999664, 124.84999847, 124.69000244, 127.30999756,125.43000031, 127.09999847, 126.90000153, 126.84999847, 125.27999878, 124.61000061, 124.27999878, 125.05999756, 123.54000092, 125.88999939, 125.90000153, 126.73999786, 127.12999725])}
Pos = {'Pos': np.array([ 0,  0,  1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0])}
Stop = {'Stop': np.array([  0.        ,   0.        , 122.86000061,   0.        , 128.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,0.        , 125.80000305,   0.        , 124.05000305, 0.        , 123.84999847,   0.        ,   0.        , 0.        ])}
index = pd.date_range('2022-1-1',periods = 17)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Open, **High, **Low, **Close, **Pos, **Stop), index = index)
df
              Open    High     Low   Close   Pos       Stop
Date 
2022-01-01  126.82  126.93  125.17  126.27     0       0.00                                                      
2022-01-02  126.56  126.99  124.78  124.85     0       0.00
2022-01-03  123.16  124.92  122.86  124.69     1     122.86
2022-01-04  125.23  127.72  125.10  127.31     0       0.00
2022-01-05  127.82  128.00  125.21  125.43    -1     128.00
2022-01-06  126.01  127.94  125.94  127.10     0       0.00
2022-01-07  127.82  128.32  126.32  126.90     0       0.00
2022-01-08  126.96  127.39  126.42  126.85     0       0.00
2022-01-09  126.44  127.64  125.08  125.28     0       0.00
2022-01-10  125.57  125.80  124.55  124.61    -1     125.80
2022-01-11  125.08  125.35  123.94  124.28     0       0.00
2022-01-12  124.28  125.24  124.05  125.06     1     124.05
2022-01-13  124.68  124.85  123.13  123.54     0       0.00
2022-01-14  124.07  126.16  123.85  125.89     1     123.85
2022-01-15  126.17  126.32  124.83  125.90     0       0.00
2022-01-16  126.60  128.46  126.21  126.74     0       0.00
2022-01-17  127.21  127.75  126.52  127.13     0       0.00
```

The desired result is:

```
              Open    High     Low   Close   Pos       Stop
Date    
2022-01-01  126.82  126.93  125.17  126.27     0       0.00
2022-01-02  126.56  126.99  124.78  124.85     0       0.00
2022-01-03  123.16  124.92  122.86  124.69     1     122.86
2022-01-04  125.23  127.72  125.10  127.31     1     122.86
2022-01-05  127.82  128.00  125.21  125.43    -1     128.00
2022-01-06  126.01  127.94  125.94  127.10    -1     128.00
2022-01-07  127.82  128.32  126.32  126.90     0       0.00
2022-01-08  126.96  127.39  126.42  126.85     0       0.00
2022-01-09  126.44  127.64  125.08  125.28     0       0.00
2022-01-10  125.57  125.80  124.55  124.61    -1     125.80
2022-01-11  125.08  125.35  123.94  124.28    -1     125.80
2022-01-12  124.28  125.24  124.05  125.06     1     124.05
2022-01-13  124.68  124.85  123.13  123.54     0       0.00
2022-01-14  124.07  126.16  123.85  125.89     1     123.85
2022-01-15  126.17  126.32  124.83  125.90     1     123.85
2022-01-16  126.60  128.46  126.21  126.74     1     123.85
2022-01-17  127.21  127.75  126.52  127.13     1     123.85
```

I've tried using the `groupby` and `where` mathods which produce a df that is close to the desired but does not keep the values unchanged for the subsequent rows in a group once the the criteria is breached.

```
s = df[['Pos','Stop']].mask(df['Stop'].eq(0)).ffill()
grouped = s.groupby(['Pos','Stop'])
df.update(grouped.apply(lambda g: g.where((s['Pos'] == 1) & (s['Stop'] <= df['Low']) | (s['Pos'] == -1) & (s['Stop'] >= df['High'])))
df

              Open    High     Low   Close  Pos    Stop
Date
2022-01-01  126.82  126.93  125.17  126.27  0.0    0.00
2022-01-02  126.56  126.99  124.78  124.85  0.0    0.00
2022-01-03  123.16  124.92  122.86  124.69  1.0  122.86
2022-01-04  125.23  127.72  125.10  127.31  1.0  122.86
2022-01-05  127.82  128.00  125.21  125.43 -1.0  128.00
2022-01-06  126.01  127.94  125.94  127.10 -1.0  128.00
2022-01-07  127.82  128.32  126.32  126.90  0.0    0.00
2022-01-08  126.96  127.39  126.42  126.85 -1.0  128.00
2022-01-09  126.44  127.64  125.08  125.28 -1.0  128.00
2022-01-10  125.57  125.80  124.55  124.61 -1.0  125.80
2022-01-11  125.08  125.35  123.94  124.28 -1.0  125.80
2022-01-12  124.28  125.24  124.05  125.06  1.0  124.05
2022-01-13  124.68  124.85  123.13  123.54  0.0    0.00
2022-01-14  124.07  126.16  123.85  125.89  1.0  123.85
2022-01-15  126.17  126.32  124.83  125.90  1.0  123.85
2022-01-16  126.60  128.46  126.21  126.74  1.0  123.85
2022-01-17  127.21  127.75  126.52  127.13  1.0  123.85
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `mask`, `where`, `groupby` and `cummin` methods

```
s =  df[['Pos','Stop']].mask(df['Stop'].eq(0)).ffill()

#-999 is necessary because `apply` which is used in the next line drops NaNs
grouped = s.fillna(-999).groupby(['Pos','Stop'], dropna = False)

#Identify days where stop has been breached with a NaN
grouped1 = grouped.apply( 
lambda g: g.where(
(s['Pos'] == 1) & (s['Stop'] <= df['Low']) |
(s['Pos'] == -1) & (s['Stop'] >= df['High'])
))

stop_breached = grouped1['Pos'].notna()

positions = s.assign(tmp = stop_breached).groupby(['Pos', 'Stop'])['tmp'].cummin().eq(1)

df[['Pos','Stop']] = grouped1.where(positions, 0)

print(df.round(2))
              Open    High     Low   Close  Pos    Stop
2022-01-01  126.82  126.93  125.17  126.27  0.0    0.00
2022-01-02  126.56  126.99  124.78  124.85  0.0    0.00
2022-01-03  123.16  124.92  122.86  124.69  1.0  122.86
2022-01-04  125.23  127.72  125.10  127.31  1.0  122.86
2022-01-05  127.82  128.00  125.21  125.43 -1.0  128.00
2022-01-06  126.01  127.94  125.94  127.10 -1.0  128.00
2022-01-07  127.82  128.32  126.32  126.90  0.0    0.00
2022-01-08  126.96  127.39  126.42  126.85  0.0    0.00
2022-01-09  126.44  127.64  125.08  125.28  0.0    0.00
2022-01-10  125.57  125.80  124.55  124.61 -1.0  125.80
2022-01-11  125.08  125.35  123.94  124.28 -1.0  125.80
2022-01-12  124.28  125.24  124.05  125.06  1.0  124.05
2022-01-13  124.68  124.85  123.13  123.54  0.0    0.00
2022-01-14  124.07  126.16  123.85  125.89  1.0  123.85
2022-01-15  126.17  126.32  124.83  125.90  1.0  123.85
2022-01-16  126.60  128.46  126.21  126.74  1.0  123.85
2022-01-17  127.21  127.75  126.52  127.13  1.0  123.85
```

**EDIT:** The below is an updated solution that is more concise and much faster.  See the comments for color and details.

```
Open = {'Open':np.array([126.81999969, 126.55999756, 123.16000366, 125.23000336,127.81999969, 126.01000214, 127.81999969, 126.95999908,126.44000244, 125.56999969, 125.08000183, 124.27999878,124.68000031, 124.06999969, 126.16999817, 126.59999847,127.20999908])}
High = {'High': np.array([126.93000031, 126.98999786, 124.91999817, 127.72000122,128.        , 127.94000244, 128.32000732, 127.38999939, 127.63999939, 125.80000305, 125.34999847, 125.23999786, 124.84999847, 126.16000366, 126.31999969, 128.46000671, 127.75      ])}
Low = {'Low' : np.array([125.16999817, 124.77999878, 122.86000061, 125.09999847,125.20999908, 125.94000244, 126.31999969, 126.41999817, 125.08000183, 124.55000305, 123.94000244, 124.05000305, 123.12999725, 123.84999847, 124.83000183, 126.20999908, 126.51999664])}
Close = {'Close': np.array([126.26999664, 124.84999847, 124.69000244, 127.30999756,125.43000031, 127.09999847, 126.90000153, 126.84999847, 125.27999878, 124.61000061, 124.27999878, 125.05999756, 123.54000092, 125.88999939, 125.90000153, 126.73999786, 127.12999725])}
Pos = {'Pos': np.array([ 0,  0,  1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0])}
Stop = {'Stop': np.array([  0.        ,   0.        , 122.86000061,   0.        , 128.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,0.        , 125.80000305,   0.        , 124.05000305, 0.        , 123.84999847,   0.        ,   0.        , 0.        ])}
index = pd.date_range('2022-1-1',periods = 17)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Open, **High, **Low, **Close, **Pos, **Stop), index = index)

df_tmp = df.copy()
df_tmp[['Pos','Stop']] = df_tmp[['Pos','Stop']].mask(df['Stop'].eq(0)).ffill()
df_tmp['tmp'] = (df_tmp['Pos'] == 1) & (df_tmp['Stop'] <= df_tmp['Low']) | (df_tmp['Pos'] == -1) & (df_tmp['Stop'] >= df_tmp['High'])

positions = df_tmp.groupby(['Pos', 'Stop'])['tmp'].cummin().eq(1)
df[['Pos','Stop']] = df_tmp[['Pos','Stop']].where(positions, 0)

print(df.round(2))
```

Comment: The first thing I notice was that repeated entries could have unwanted effects due to the group by. This means that a `Pos`-`Stop`-combination occurs again later, which is still in the same group. For example, add following row at the end `[2022-01-18, 126.81999969,126.81999969,126.81999969,126.81999969,1, 128.]` of your dataframe and look at the results.

Comment: Honestly, I am also not too sure if your solution is much faster. Did you benchmark the two solutions? Out of curiosity how many rows does your full dataset have?

Comment: @JANO While it's certainly possible that a duplicate record could appear within a group it almost surely will not occur.  These are records of stock prices (real #'s) & are (almost) uncountably infinite.  Thus it's nearly impossible that two days will have precisely the same OHLC values.  With regard to speed, the vectorized approach (2s) takes less than half the time vs the `for` loop  approach (5s) when applied to ~10000 records.  However this is only a small sample since the # of records in production will be higher by at least 3 orders of magnitude so the time saved could be bw 3-10 hours.

Comment: Very interesting thank you. I had a deeper look at your answer. The trick with `cummin()` is very impressive. I have to remember that. I posted some alternative statements that might speed up your code even more. Would you mind testing the time for them?

Comment: @JANO The speed improvement is significant from 2s down to 0.5s so an improvement of 4X.  Can't thank you enough.  Your suggestions also make the code more concise.  I guess the lesson is that `groupby` and `apply` combine to be expensive operations.

Comment: Glad I could help! The `groupby`s were also the reason why I thought the simple loop solution could still be more efficient. But now with a 10x faster solution, I'm convinced that your solution is better.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest iterating over all rows and checking for both of the conditions. Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your result as your code generates a different dataframe. Nonetheless, I think the following code does what you need:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

Open = {'Open':np.array([126.81999969, 126.55999756, 123.16000366, 125.23000336,127.81999969, 126.01000214, 127.81999969, 126.95999908,126.44000244, 125.56999969, 125.08000183, 124.27999878,124.68000031, 124.06999969, 126.16999817, 126.59999847,127.20999908])}
High = {'High': np.array([126.93000031, 126.98999786, 124.91999817, 127.72000122,128.        , 127.94000244, 128.32000732, 127.38999939, 127.63999939, 125.80000305, 125.34999847, 125.23999786, 124.84999847, 126.16000366, 126.31999969, 128.46000671, 127.75      ])}
Low = {'Low' : np.array([125.16999817, 124.77999878, 122.86000061, 125.09999847,125.20999908, 125.94000244, 126.31999969, 126.41999817, 125.08000183, 124.55000305, 123.94000244, 124.05000305, 123.12999725, 123.84999847, 124.83000183, 126.20999908, 126.51999664])}
Close = {'Close': np.array([126.26999664, 124.84999847, 124.69000244, 127.30999756,125.43000031, 127.09999847, 126.90000153, 126.84999847, 125.27999878, 124.61000061, 124.27999878, 125.05999756, 123.54000092, 125.88999939, 125.90000153, 126.73999786, 127.12999725])}
Pos = {'Pos': np.array([ 0,  0,  1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0])}
Stop = {'Stop': np.array([  0.        ,   0.        , 122.86000061,   0.        , 128.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,0.        , 125.80000305,   0.        , 124.05000305, 0.        , 123.84999847,   0.        ,   0.        , 0.        ])}
index = pd.date_range('2022-1-1',periods = 17)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Open, **High, **Low, **Close, **Pos, **Stop), index = index)

# Produce iterable index
df = df.reset_index()

# Iterate over every row
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    curr_pos  = df.loc[i, 'Pos']
    curr_stop = df.loc[i, 'Stop']
    curr_low = df.loc[i, 'Low']
    curr_high = df.loc[i, 'High']
    prev_pos = df.loc[i-1, 'Pos'] 
    prev_stop = df.loc[i-1, 'Stop']
    
    # Check your conditions
    if ((prev_pos == -1) and (curr_high > prev_stop)) or ((prev_pos == 1) and (curr_low < prev_stop)):
        df.loc[i, 'Pos'] = prev_pos
        df.loc[i, 'Stop'] = prev_stop

# Restore original index
df = df.set_index('index')       
df
```

EDIT: Based on your solution, I tried to remove some operations that I think are costly. Would you mind testing the following code:

```
Open = {'Open':np.array([126.81999969, 126.55999756, 123.16000366, 125.23000336,127.81999969, 126.01000214, 127.81999969, 126.95999908,126.44000244, 125.56999969, 125.08000183, 124.27999878,124.68000031, 124.06999969, 126.16999817, 126.59999847,127.20999908])}
High = {'High': np.array([126.93000031, 126.98999786, 124.91999817, 127.72000122,128.        , 127.94000244, 128.32000732, 127.38999939, 127.63999939, 125.80000305, 125.34999847, 125.23999786, 124.84999847, 126.16000366, 126.31999969, 128.46000671, 127.75      ])}
Low = {'Low' : np.array([125.16999817, 124.77999878, 122.86000061, 125.09999847,125.20999908, 125.94000244, 126.31999969, 126.41999817, 125.08000183, 124.55000305, 123.94000244, 124.05000305, 123.12999725, 123.84999847, 124.83000183, 126.20999908, 126.51999664])}
Close = {'Close': np.array([126.26999664, 124.84999847, 124.69000244, 127.30999756,125.43000031, 127.09999847, 126.90000153, 126.84999847, 125.27999878, 124.61000061, 124.27999878, 125.05999756, 123.54000092, 125.88999939, 125.90000153, 126.73999786, 127.12999725])}
Pos = {'Pos': np.array([ 0,  0,  1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0])}
Stop = {'Stop': np.array([  0.        ,   0.        , 122.86000061,   0.        , 128.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,0.        , 125.80000305,   0.        , 124.05000305, 0.        , 123.84999847,   0.        ,   0.        , 0.        ])}
index = pd.date_range('2022-1-1',periods = 17)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Open, **High, **Low, **Close, **Pos, **Stop), index = index)

df_tmp = df.copy()
df_tmp[['Pos','Stop']] = df_tmp[['Pos','Stop']].mask(df['Stop'].eq(0)).ffill()
df_tmp['tmp'] = (df_tmp['Pos'] == 1) & (df_tmp['Stop'] <= df_tmp['Low']) | (df_tmp['Pos'] == -1) & (df_tmp['Stop'] >= df_tmp['High'])

positions = df_tmp.groupby(['Pos', 'Stop'])['tmp'].cummin().eq(1)
df[['Pos','Stop']] = df_tmp[['Pos','Stop']].where(positions, 0)

print(df.round(2))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying for vectorized solution without for loops.  Separately but related, I corrected the typos so the code should now be reproducible.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to read the title again. I am not sure if you can find a vectorized solution for your problem as each row depends on an arbitrary number of previous rows, which can only be calculated in order. Regarding your data, I think it is still not entirely correct. E.g. the row with date `2022-01-04`: The previous row has pos `1.0`. So, we check condition 2: current low `125.10` smaller than prior stop `122.86`. This is false and the current pos should remain `0.0`. However, in your desired result the current pos is `1.0`.

Comment: You are correct. I mixed up the inequalities which I've since corrected and updated. The code, however, expresses the correct relationships.   Regarding vectorization, I have posted a vectorized solution. Curious as to your thoughts.  Thank you. –

Comment: I have a look at it and write it under your answer